# How to move a file from sdcard to app data folder?

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

In my app I need to move files from the sdcard to /data/data/com.pack.main/ folder.The code I am using is this:

```
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File directory = cw.getDir("/data/data/com.cuelearn.main/", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File mypath=new File(directory,object.VIDEO_FILENAME+".mp4");
            copyFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/cue_learn_data/video_files/"+object.VIDEO_FILENAME+".mp4"),mypath);
```

and the copyFile() method is:

```
                public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException
            {
                System.out.println("copying files");
                FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
                FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();

                try
                {
                    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (inChannel != null)
                        inChannel.close();
                    if (outChannel != null)
                        outChannel.close();
                }
            }
```

Can any one tell me where I am going wrong. The file in the sdcard is present but still not working.May be anyone could give me a easier way to do this?

Comment: the /data/data folder can not be accessed only by root user

Comment: you can not.. or at least you can not if your mobile is not rooted

Comment: or you can try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29

Comment: That was good but I want to copy it to internal storage this will copy it again to sdcard!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29 this call will returns the /data/data/yourapp/cach path

Comment: can you help me if You have time ..on chat?

Comment: inside your activity change File directory = cw.getDir("/data/data/com.cuelearn.main/", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); with  File directory = getCacheDir();