# How can i restore my database to its original directory?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

Here is the code to save/copy my data in to SDcard,when i click on Backup Button my database saved in sdcard in NOTEIT directory and now i want to restore this database when i click on restore button into my default directory so can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

```
public static void backupDatabase() throws IOException 
{
    try
    {
    File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.neelrazin.noteit/databases/data");

        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NOTEIT");

        if (!exportDir.exists()) 
        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());

        file.createNewFile();

        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(dbFile).getChannel();  //fails here

        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();

        try 
        {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463686/how-to-move-a-file-from-sdcard-to-app-data-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the restore is an exact opposite of your backup.

**Like this**:

```
public static void restoreDatabase() throws IOException 
{
    try
    {
    File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.neelrazin.noteit/databases/data");

        File importDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NOTEIT");

        if (!importDir.exists()) 
        {
            throw new IOException("External 'NOTEIT' directory does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        File file = new File(importDir, dbFile.getName());
        if (!file.exists()) 
        {
            throw new IOException("Does not exist external db file: NOTEIT/" + dbFile.getName());
            return;
        }

        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dbFile).getChannel();

        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();

        try 
        {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace? Any exceptions?

Comment: it give this 'NOTEIT' directory does not exist."

Comment: You're welcome. `'NOTEIT' directory does not exist` indicates that `backupDatabase()` did not successfully complete prior to you running `restoreDatabase()`. This is correct and intended behavior.

Comment: it save my database in sdcard 
now i can also restore it
thanx a lot